# Why are ALU outputs undefined?

Tags: verilog, fpga, alu

I am designing an ALU in Verilog while I am learning it. I came up with the following code:

Testbench:

```
module ALUtb;

reg clock = 1'b0;

reg [0:7] val1;
reg [0:7] val2;

initial begin
   val1 = 8'b01010100;
   val2 = 8'b10101000;
   #50 $finish;
 end
 ALU piet(val1, val2,, clock);

always begin
  #5 clock = ~clock
  ;
end
endmodule

 // Main code:

 module ALU(
     a1, a2, out, clock
     );

  output [0:7] out;
  input [0:7] a1;
  input [0:7] a2;
  input clock;

  wire clock;
  reg  out;
  wire co;
  wire a1, a2;

   wire [0:7] poep;

   initial begin
     $monitor("Out=%d, co=%d, a=%d, a2=%d, poep=%d, clock=%d", out, co, a1, a2, poep, clock);
  end

  always @ (posedge clock) begin
     out <= poep;
  end

  adder addy(.output_byte(poep), .co(co), .a1(a1), .a2(a2), .clock(clock));
endmodule 

 module adder(
   output_byte, co, a1, a2, clock
  );
  initial begin
    output_byte = 8'b00000011;
  end
  input [0:7] a1;
  input [0:7] a2;
  input clock;

  output [0:7] output_byte;
  output output_bit;

  output co;

  wire c1;
  reg b1, b2;
  reg [0:7] output_byte;
  wire output_bit;

  integer i;

  always @ (posedge clock) begin
     for(i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1) begin

      b1 = (a1[i] & (1 << i));
      b2 = (a2[i] & (1 << i));  

      #1 output_byte[i] = output_bit;
  end
  end

 bitadder b_adder(.out(output_bit), .co(), .a1(b1), .a2(b2), .c1(c1));

endmodule

 // Deze module is een 1-bits adder. 
 module bitadder(out, co, a1, a2, c1);

  output out, co;
  input a1, a2, c1;

  wire out, co;

  wire a1;
  wire a2;
  wire c1;

  assign {co, out} = a1 + a2 + c1;

endmodule
```

In the output, I am getting:

```
Out=  x, co=z, a= 84, a2=168, poep=  3, clock=0
Out=  3, co=z, a= 84, a2=168, poep=  x, clock=1
Out=  3, co=z, a= 84, a2=168, poep=  x, clock=0
Out=  x, co=z, a= 84, a2=168, poep=  x, clock=1
Out=  x, co=z, a= 84, a2=168, poep=  x, clock=0
Out=  x, co=z, a= 84, a2=168, poep=  x, clock=1
Out=  x, co=z, a= 84, a2=168, poep=  x, clock=0
Out=  x, co=z, a= 84, a2=168, poep=  x, clock=1
Out=  x, co=z, a= 84, a2=168, poep=  x, clock=0
Out=  x, co=z, a= 84, a2=168, poep=  x, clock=1
Out=  x, co=z, a= 84, a2=168, poep=  x, clock=0
```

As you can see, this is only an 8-bit adder. Since even this doesn't work yet, we haven't yet proceeded.

Why isn't the output changing properly? `poep` is like a buffer for the actual output `out`. `co` is the carry-out bit, a is the first number, `a2` is the second number, `c1` is the carry-in bit, and the rest should speak for itself.

Why are my outputs undefined?

Comment: `#1 output_byte[i] = output_bit;` is not synthesizable. You do not even need the `always` block in `adder`, you need 8 `bitadder` linked together

Answer (score 0):

Your outputs are undefined because you never assigned a value to the `c1` signal inside the `adder` module.  You declared `c1` as a `wire`, which defaults to the high-impedance value (z).  The problem is that you never drive it with a known value.

Connecting `c1` to the input of `bitadder` results in that module's outputs becoming unknown (x), and that unknown propagates up through the module hierarchy.

The simplest fix is to change:

```
  wire c1;
```

to:

```
  wire c1 = 0;
```

That clears up the unknown outputs:

```
Out=x, co=z, a=0, a2=0, poep=  3, clock=0
Out=1, co=z, a=0, a2=0, poep=  3, clock=1
Out=1, co=z, a=0, a2=0, poep=  3, clock=0
Out=1, co=z, a=0, a2=0, poep=  1, clock=0
Out=1, co=z, a=0, a2=0, poep=  0, clock=0
Out=0, co=z, a=0, a2=0, poep=  0, clock=1
Out=0, co=z, a=0, a2=0, poep=  0, clock=0
Out=0, co=z, a=0, a2=0, poep=  0, clock=1
Out=0, co=z, a=0, a2=0, poep=  0, clock=0
Out=0, co=z, a=0, a2=0, poep=  0, clock=1
Out=0, co=z, a=0, a2=0, poep=  0, clock=0
Out=0, co=z, a=0, a2=0, poep=  0, clock=1
```

---

My simulators gave me a compile error on the `output_byte` signal in the `adder` module.  I deleted this line to get rid of the compile error:

```
  output output_bit;
```